# Using const in es6 for of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

While x is not a constant, how the following code runs without any errors?

```
for (const x of [1,2,3]){
console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: try doing x=x+1 inside the for let me go how it goes

Comment: In IE11 I *do* get an error when I run it: "Const must be initialised".

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid for/in left-hand side` on Firefox

Comment: works fine here : https://jsbin.com/solisa/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @JordanHendrix You are using Babel, which converts `const` to `var`.

Comment: understood, lets get some more info, Duke, how are you running this? actually just checked, seems to work without babel too --- in chrome(just saw your answer) https://jsbin.com/kasoxo/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 6):

It works on compliant browsers like Chrome because they create a new, different, constant variable at each iteration:

```
var arr = [];
for (const x of [1,2,3])
  arr.push(() => x);
arr.map(f => f()); // [1,2,3] on Chrome
```

Some non-compliant browsers reuse the same variable instead:

```
var arr = [];
for (let x of [1,2,3])
  arr.push(() => x);
arr.map(f => f()); // [3,3,3] on non-compliant browsers
```

Therefore, they throw an error if in the example above you use `const`.

---

[Runtime Semantics: ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset) says:

> 5. Repeat
>
>    7. Else
>
>       1. Assert: *lhsKind* is lexicalBinding.
>       2. Assert: *lhs* is a *ForDeclaration*.
>       3. Let *iterationEnv* be [NewDeclarativeEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-newdeclarativeenvironment)(*oldEnv*).
>       4. Perform [BindingInstantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-bindinginstantiation) for *lhs* passing *iterationEnv* as the argument.

So each iteration should create a new binding. Chrome is correct.